# PHP script to get CPU utilization for each process?

Tags: php, windows, cpu, utilization

How do I get the CPU usage for each process that is currently running on the local system or server using PHP.

How can I use the Command Prompt command `tasklist` from within PHP and fetch process names and memory information.

Here is the example :

```
Name of Processor     Memory usage
Edit plus              6.1 MB
Google Chrome           20 MB
Command Prompt           5 MB
Tomcat                 2.1 MB
```

Comment: An extension called [Win32ps](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.win32ps.php) exists for Windows Servers that 'allows PHP retrieve statistics about process and memory utilization.'

Comment: I am using Xampp web server, but the server i am referring to is Local System like windows task manager which shows process names and their memory usage, i want to fetch the same data but only process name and memory usage using PHP script

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seeing as you've changed the specification for the answer and I don't wish to remove or butcher my other answer which may be an acceptable solution for others.

If you **MUST** use the Command Prompt command `tasklist` to retrieve the process data then you can then call this Application using [`exec()`](https://www.php.net/function.exec) from PHP.

```
<?php
exec('tasklist.exe', $outputLines);

foreach($line in $outputLines)
{
    //Extract information from String...
}
?>
```

You will then need to use String manipulation to extract the information you want.  Regex might be a good choice.

Answer (score 1):

**For non-windows systems** (*windows tag was added after this answer was given*):

Probably you want to use whatever Service your Servers Operating System porovides for this and access it via PHP. If you a on a Unix machine, there probably is a Command Line tool like ps.

```
ps aux | less
```

Read up on `ps` [here](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/show-all-running-processes-in-linux/).

You can execute this and fetch the output using [exec](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php) in php.

```
echo exec('ps aux | less');
```

you could parse that output easily using [PHP String manipulation functions](https://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.strings.php).

Comment: @FlashThunder That Windows tag was added after i answered. This answer is still valid and might be usefull for people coming here searching for a general solution.

Comment: Ok sorry then... I can't un`-1` it until it won't be edited :(

Answer (score 1):

There is a PECL package for reporting on **Windows Processes** called Win32ps ([PHP Manual Page](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.win32ps.php) | [PECL Page](http://pecl.php.net/package/win32ps)).

With this extension you should be able to retrieve and output a running processes list like so:

```
<?php
$procs = win32_ps_stat_proc();

foreach($proc in $procs)
{
    echo basename($proc['exe']) . " - " . $proc['mem']['working_set_size'] . "\r\n";
}
?>
```

This is a **Microsoft Windows** only solution.